# Vim/command-T: Ignoring "gem-name" because its extensions are not built. Try gem pristine "gem-name"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, vim, vim-plugin

Whenever I open the command-T plugin for the first time in MacVim, I get the following terminal:

```
Ignoring atomic-1.1.13 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine atomic-1.1.13
Ignoring atomic-1.1.10 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine atomic-1.1.10
Ignoring bcrypt-3.1.7 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine bcrypt-3.1.7
Ignoring bcrypt-ruby-3.0.1 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine bcrypt-ruby-3.0.1
Ignoring eventmachine-1.0.3 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine eventmachine-1.0.3
Ignoring executable-hooks-1.3.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine executable-hooks-1.3.2
Ignoring ffi-1.9.3 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine ffi-1.9.3
Ignoring ffi-1.9.0 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine ffi-1.9.0
Ignoring ffi-1.4.0 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine ffi-1.4.0
Ignoring gem-wrappers-1.2.4 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine gem-wrappers-1.2.4
Ignoring json-1.8.1 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine json-1.8.1
Ignoring json-1.8.0 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine json-1.8.0
Ignoring nokogiri-1.6.3.1 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri-1.6.3.1
Ignoring nokogiri-1.6.0 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri-1.6.0
Ignoring nokogiri-1.5.6 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri-1.5.6
Ignoring pg-0.17.1 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine pg-0.17.1
Ignoring pg-0.17.0 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine pg-0.17.0
Ignoring pg-0.15.1 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine pg-0.15.1
Ignoring pg-0.14.1 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine pg-0.14.1
Ignoring sqlite3-1.3.9 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine sqlite3-1.3.9
Ignoring sqlite3-1.3.8 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine sqlite3-1.3.8
Ignoring sqlite3-1.3.7 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine sqlite3-1.3.7
Ignoring thin-1.6.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine thin-1.6.2
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you follow the instructions when you installed command-T. I think the answer is no.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you skipped the installation for command-T. From the doc

> The C extension must also be then compiled; for instance, if Vimball installs your plugin files in ~/.vim, then you would do this:

```
cd ~/.vim/ruby/command-t 
ruby extconf.rb 
make
```

---

Also note that command T and vim must be compiled against the same version of ruby.

Answer (score 3):

I recently switched to from `rvm` to `chruby` and ran `gem update --system`, thats when the issue began occurring for me. After that, anytime I ran bundle I was slaughtered with the same warnings.

`Ignoring curb-0.8.6 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine curb-0.8.6`

This, plus dozens of other warnings for other gems.

Not sure what fixed it, but I did 2 things and the warning disappeared:

```
gem update bundler
gem install curb
```